# Can not trigger Calculate method on another worksheet even though the sheet calculates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have Sheet1 where I choose a customer.
The idea is that one customer can get one invoice per day.

On Sheet2 I have a named range that calculates if that customer already had an invoice on that day.

So, condition is very simple "InvoiceToday" equals one is a warning.

I want that warning to signal the user through a change of a background picture.

My idea was to put the code into Sheet2 Calculate event!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
MsgBox ("calculate")
    
    Pic = Range("BackgroundPicture").Value

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(2)


    If Range("NumberOfInvoicesToday") > 0 Then
        ws.SetBackgroundPicture Filename:=Pic
    Else
        ws.SetBackgroundPicture Filename:=""

    End If
End Sub
```

It does not trigger (tested with msgbox).
It only triggers if the calculation is initiated by something on Sheet2.

What should I do to make it trigger?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean under VBA tag?

Comment: You need more detail here - how is that named range calculating? if it depends upon a pivot table then you need to refresh tables; there is too much detail lacking here for me to make sense of the story - sorry.  (external workbook links? what does "choose a customer" mean - do you have a drop down validation list or some other macro? show a screenshot / show the named range function / something pls ta  Calculate
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
ActiveSheet.Calculate

Comment: Fair point. I gave up on the concept because it is painfully slow even if it sometimes succeds. Here is the formula that calculates Number of invoices today. =COUNTIFS(HonorarnotenTable[Datum],">"&TODAY(),HonorarnotenTable[Datum],"<"&TODAY()+1,HonorarnotenTable[CustomerNoHon], "=" & CustomerNo)